# How do I create an error alert for an invalid input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating a date input and I want an error alert if the date input is left blank.

currently I have and it doesnt work:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateDate(value) {
  var a = document.getElementById("date").value;
  if (a = = = "") {
    window.alert("Error");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Tee Time Sign-up Form</h1>
<form>
 <div id="teeDate">
      Date:<input type=“date” id=“date” name=“date”><br>
     <button id=teeTime onClick="validateDate()">Submit</button><br>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put spaces in your operators, use `===` not `= = =`, a better use to say if `a !== ""` if `a` is NOT an empty string

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Tee Time Sign-up Form</h1>
    <form>
      <div id="teeDate">
        Date:<input type="date" id="date" name="date" /><br />
        <button id="teeTime">Submit</button><br />
      </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var button = document.getElementById("teeTime");

      function validateDate(value) {
        if (value === "") {
          window.alert("Error");
          return false;
        }
      }

      button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var value = document.getElementById("date").value;
        validateDate(value);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this also didn't work, it seems as if my functions are not being run as I am not getting an alert window

Comment: Hold on, I jus tnoticed, your function takes in an argument `value` but you never pass that in inside your input field

Comment: @Courtney try the code i updated just now, you also had 2 sets of double quotes in your html attributes